# Move files from directories listed in file

Tags: shell, loops, cp

I have a directory structure like the following toy example

```
DirectoryTo
DirectoryFrom
-Dir1
---File1.txt
---File2.txt
---File3.txt
-Dir2
---File4.txt
---File5.txt
---File6.txt
-Dir3
---File1.txt
---File5.txt
---File7.txt
```

I'm trying to copy all the files from DirectoryFrom to DirectoryTo, keeping the newer file if there are duplicates.

```
DirectoryTo
-File1.txt
-File2.txt
-File3.txt
-File4.txt
-File5.txt
-File6.txt
-File7.txt
DirectoryFrom
-Dir1
---File1.txt
---File2.txt
---File3.txt
-Dir2
---File4.txt
---File5.txt
---File6.txt
-Dir3
---File1.txt
---File5.txt
---File7.txt
```

I've created a text file with a list of all the subdirectories.  This list is in the order such that the NEWEST files will be listed first:

Filelist.txt

```
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir1
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir2
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir3
```

**So what I'd like to do is loop through each directory in Filelist.txt, copy the files, and NOT replace if the file already exists.**

I'd like to do this at the command line, in a shell script, or possibly in Python.  I'm pretty new to Python, but have a little experience with the command line.  However, I've never done something this complicated.

In reality, I have ~60 folders, each with 50-200 files in them, to give you a feel for how many I have.  Also, each file is ~75MB.

I've done something similar in R before, but it's slow and not really meant for this.  But here's what I've tried for a shell script, edited to fit this toy example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in Filelist.txt
do
    cp -n line C:/DirectoryTo/
done
```

Comment: If you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash and replace `cp -n line` by `cp -n "$line"`, you're there, I'd say.

Comment: consider using rsync: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one one directory level in your `DirectoryFrom` then you can use:

```
cp -n DirectoryFrom/*/* DirectoryTo
```

**explanation :** copy every file which exist in subdirectories of DirectoryFrom to DirectoryTo if it doesn't exist

n flag is for not overwriting files if they already exist.

`cp` will also ignore directories if they exist in subdirectories of DirectoryTo

Comment: I'm trying this now.  I assume it goes through directories in alphabetical order?  If so, this will work for me.  Otherwise, I need to be able to tell it the order of directories.

Comment: @GaiusAugustus yes traversal is alphabatically

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create test environnement :
mkdir C:/DirectoryTo
mkdir C:/DirectoryFrom
cd C:/DirectoryFrom
mkdir Dir1 Dir2 Dir3 
(
cat << EOF
Dir1/File1.txt
Dir1/File2.txt
Dir1/File3.txt
Dir2/File4.txt
Dir2/File5.txt
Dir2/File6.txt
Dir3/File1.txt
Dir3/File5.txt
Dir3/File7.txt
EOF
)| while read f
do
echo "$f : `date`" 
echo "$f : `date`" > $f
sleep 1
done


# create Filelist.txt file :
(
cat << EOF
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir1
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir2
C:/DirectoryFrom/Dir3
EOF
) > Filelist.txt


# Generate the liste of all files : 
cd C:/DirectoryFrom
cat Filelist.txt | while read f; do ls -1 $f; done | sort -u > filenames.txt
cat filenames.txt


# liste of all files path, sorted by time order :
cd C:/DirectoryFrom
ls -1tr */* > all_filespath_sorted.txt
cat all_filespath_sorted.txt


# selected files to be copied :
cat  filenames.txt | while read f; do cat all_filespath_sorted.txt | grep $f | tail -1 ; done


# copy of selected files:
cat  filenames.txt | while read f; do cat all_filespath_sorted.txt | grep $f | tail -1 ; done | while read c
do
echo $c
cp -p $c C:/DirectoryTo
done

# verifying :
cd C:/DirectoryTo
ls -ltr

# or
ls -1 | while read f; do echo -e "\n$f\n-------"; cat $f; done



#------------------------------------------------
# Other solution for a limited number of files :
#------------------------------------------------

# To list files by order :
find `cat  Filelist.txt | xargs` -type f | xargs ls -1tr 

# To copy files, the newer will replace the older :
find `cat  Filelist.txt | xargs` -type f | xargs ls -1tr | while read c
do
echo $c
cp -p $c C:/DirectoryTo
done
```